# Phaser Dom Ui Not responding to add event listener

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I've been trying to make an interactive ui using the phaser DOM, and i've loaded a `ui.html` file through  `this.add.dom(0, 0).createFromCache('ui');` and I've tried adding an event listener to a button in that file, but it doesn't appear to respond, as the `console.log` doesn't log, neither do i get errors

query selector code

```js
 document.querySelector("#dirt").addEventListener(
      "click",
      function () {
        console.log("add dirt")
      }
    );
```

```html
<button id="dirt">+</button>
```

Comment: There is no issue with the code you posted, so whatever is wrong, you're not showing us. Maybe there's an invisible element over the button, blocking clicks. Maybe the button is submitting a form, and resetting the page. Maybe the button is getting recreated after you attach the event listener. Or maybe there is an error you're ignoring, or try/catching and ignoring. Or most likely, there's another element with id `dirt` that's getting the event listener.

Comment: Where and when are you setting the `EventListener`? in the  Phaser code or outside? in the `create`  function?

Comment: entire example - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/phaserui

Comment: i add it in the update func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First **never** add `EventListeners` in the `update` function. Since doing this will add 60 `EventListeners` per second. This will cause always performance issues and cause many unexpected side effects, and also is the cause of you problem.

Move the `addEventListener` code into the `create` function, than it will work.
*(I changed it in the demo and it worked fine)*.